# Guardian and custom user model: IntegrityError on migration, creating anonymous user

Tags: mysql, django, django-guardian

I have this model file with custom  user defined in it.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin, GuardianUserMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,
            verbose_name='email address', unique=True)
    first_name    = models.CharField('first name', max_length=15,blank=False)
    last_name     = models.CharField('last name', max_length=15,blank=True)
    date_joined   = models.DateTimeField('date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    slug          = models.SlugField('slug', max_length=50, unique=True, null=True) 
    is_active     = models.BooleanField('active',default=True)


    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


    class Meta:
    app_label = "latiro_app"
    db_table =  "users"


        permissions = (
                ("view_user", "view User"),
                ("edit_profile", "Edit Profile"),
                )


    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name


    def generate_user_slug(self):
        max_length = CustomUser._meta.get_field('slug').max_length
        full_name = self.get_full_name()
        slug = original = slugify(full_name)[:max_length]

        for i in itertools.count(1):
            if not CustomUser.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
                break

            slug = '{0}-{1}' .format(original[:max_length - len(str(i)) - 1], i)
        return slug


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.generate_user_slug()
        super().save()         


def get_anonymous_user_instance(CustomUser):
    return CustomUser(first_name='Anonymous')


class Profile (models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE,
                                    null=False, verbose_name='list of users')
    phone_regex   = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}')
    phone_number  = models.CharField('phone number', validators=[phone_regex], max_length=50, blank=True)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    province        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_profile/%y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    followers       = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    following       = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

And this signal

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if kwargs.get('created', True) and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
            profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile,
              sender = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

When run first migrations, Django finishes migrating my app into the database well. But when I run migrations the second time, Django throws this error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key
>   'email'").

I'm using MySQL. What is going wrong here?

UPDATE: I have found the code that is throwing errors when i make second migrations.

I have this code in my model file:

```
def get_anonymous_user_instance(CustomUser):
    return CustomUser(first_name='Anonymous')
```

I imported this function into my settings so that when i make migrations for the first time,  anonymous user will be created. and ofcource it does as expected. But when i run migrations again, django  attempt to create another anonymous user, that  is why i get this error.

When i comment out this line in my settings:

"
GUARDIAN_GET_INIT_ANONYMOUS_USER = 'latiro_app.models.get_anonymous_user_instance'
"

I don't see this error.

Comment: Apparently you are creating users with an empty `email`, and since it is unique, it fails when adding the second user. It's hard to tell how it's happening, particularly in a migration, without more details about how you are creating the users.

Comment: I'm creating a custom user with django abstractbaseuser , i posted my code  above

Comment: You posted the code that defines a user, but not how you are actually using it. You need to make sure the `email` field is not empty.

Comment: forgive me mate, my purpose here is to create a user upon signup with the custom user model i posted above and later edit user profile with Prpfile model class have  one to one relationship with custom user class.

Comment: the code above works and i can create user and super user, but the problem comes when  i want to run second migrations of my app.

Comment: Ok, but however you are doing it, there is code running that creates the users (form processing, Django's `createsuperuser`, migrations, etc). And you need to make sure the `email` field is not empty when you create a user.

Comment: What actually must be in email field before i create an user?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The email address of the user must be in that field, and it's not necessarily *before* you create the user. You can run `CustomUser.objects.create(email=user@example.com)`, or you can create the object first and then assign an e-mail. You just have to make sure the field is not empty (and, of course, that it's unique) before you save another user.

Comment: I'm updated my question. i'm using django guardian to create permission per user.

Answer (score 1):

`email` is a unique field, so you can't have two `CustomUser`s with the same `e-mail`. Guardian is creating a new user from the object returned by the callable in the `GUARDIAN_GET_INIT_ANONYMOUS_USER` setting, so it attempts to create the same user and fails. You can work around this by using `get_or_create`:

```
def get_anonymous_guardian_user_instance(CustomUser):
    user, _ = CustomUser.objects.get_or_create(
        first_name='Anonymous',
        email='guardian@example.com',
    )
    return user
```

There is actually a [Guardian issue](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/473) about this, but unfortunately it's not resolved and it's not clear if it should be a problem. The documentation [cautions the user about `syncdb`](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html?highlight=GUARDIAN_GET_INIT_ANONYMOUS_USER#guardian-get-init-anonymous-user), but in my opinion it's not very clear about what the callable should return, in the [section about creating anonymous users](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/custom-user-model.html#anonymous-user-creation) (it doesn't deal with the `unique` constraint).

Comment: Thanks for for your patience mate. I tried it but i'm still getting the same error when running migrations.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because in the mean time I saw there's a ticket about this, I updated the answer.

Comment: I think the latest edit should work with no workarounds.

Comment: Obrigando Irmao. It works and no more conflits. "get_or_create" is a magic to this. This line: "return CustomUser(first_name='Anonymous', email='guardian@example.com')"  here realy blinded me. I coudn't realise that this is causing django guardian to perform save to an instance that is statically waiting to be saved.

Comment: Exactly, if you return a freshly created `CustomUser` to Guardian, it will just `save` it and attempt to create a new object with it. This is not very clear in the Guardian documentation. They caution the user about `syncdb` (this was probably long ago), but they don't say exactly what will be done with the instance that you return. I had assumed they would do something like `get_or_create` themselves, but they don't.